# Gradle builds a jar without classes

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

*build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

version = '1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'app.Main'
    }
}

repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}
```

*Main.java*:

```
package app;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I need to build a jar, so I could run it from command line

```
java -Xms6000m -Xmx7100m -jar sample.jar
```

My project is more complex than "Hello World", the problem I am trying to solve is that my jar has only `MANIFEST` file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: app.Main
```

I created my project in Eclipse IDE with buildship plugin. (I do not think there is a problem)
I build my project in command line.

```
gradlew clean build
```

Command line output

```
C:\Development\Workspaces\training\sample>gradlew clean build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
C:\Development\Workspaces\training\memoryAllocation2>
```

My project structure.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that file should be named `gradle.build`? You named `gradle.build` or maybe misspelled it in your question

Comment: Yes, it is `build.gradle`. I updated my question.

Comment: What is your complete file structure? Specifically where is your `Main.java` file?

Comment: Where are your source files located?

Comment: I updated my question and added a screen with my project structure.

Comment: Too much green, sorry. What is the exact path in the filesystem to `Main.java`?

Comment: OK, I will update in two mins.

Comment: The question is, if your packages start right under `src` or under `src/main/java`.

Comment: `src/main/java` actually

Comment: Yeah, I'm on mobile and already clicked 'Post' when I noticed ...

Comment: Why do you have `com.app.Main` in the manifest when you configure it to be `app.Main`?

Comment: @lu.koerfer You can put your comment as an answer, and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @Vampire You are right, it was not `src/main/java`!!!

Comment: Btw. if you want to have a standalone app as result with windows and *nix start scripts, libraries and maybe additional files, you might consider using the `application` plugin instead of building a runnable JAR file which depends on the user having JARs associated with the Java executable and not e. g. with some archiving tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source files are not matching your build script. You either have to put your files in the conventional `src/main/java/` directory, or change your build script to tell Gradle where to find the source files.

Comment: The magic keyword to change the place where Gradle looks for source files is **source sets**.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the various comments into one complete answer:

Gradle uses, just like Maven, a approach called *convention over configuration*. This also includes a convention for the location of source files. Without any configuration, Gradle expects the source files for your application under `src/main/java`. Test sources can be placed under `src/test/java`.